# Reset tasks for using multiple times

Tags: tasks, task-list

I'm creating a list with tasks that I don't want people to share at the same time, I don't want them to edit the exact same list simultaneously. But rather have it as a finished file that people can grab and use, and all the list's settings would be set to standard, ready for use. And THEN the user can edit it, to later on scrap it when the tasks are complete, and after that pick the same task list again to use.

So is there a way for each user to kind of reset the list only for his/her needs?

I'm using the app "tasks" and is pretty much finished with it's functions but it's just this problem left.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an individual Task-List foreach user (or rather let them create it by themselfes).

You could also create an template from your preferred tasklist-configuration. 
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/10/14/using-list-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/

The only other option to personalize a list (other than item level permissions) are the views which can be customized by each with contribute permission.

### Update for questions in comments

I actually testet this and you don't need to modify the .stp since SharePoint is quite smart when adding a template.

But since i wrote this already here's a newbe tutorial.

**How to get a ContentType's ID via the UI:**

Go to Site *Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Site content types*

Klick your desired ContentType
[image]

Look at the URL and find something like `ctype=0x0108005B084DD0C9808148B20B6C9450DA78F5`

Thats the ContentType's ID.

**The template I've created does not have the same content type ID as the original list's content type's ID?:**

Yes. If you add a ContentType to a list, the ContentType is only the base for a new ContentType created explicitly for the list. This is necessary due to the fact that you can modify a ContentType in a list without any inpact on the other references of this ContentType.

You can validate this by adding the contenttype to the list and view it in the list settings. [image]

The ContentType you started with is the parent. You can also have a look at the url again. [image]

The generated id starts exactly like its parent but there is a postfix generated for this unique ContentType.

**How to modify a .stp:**

Here's some reference : 
https://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/manually-edit-a-stp-manifest-template-file-for-sharepoint/

**What needs to be changed:**

Search for all references of your ContentType ID and trimm the part that is not the parent ContentType. 
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: I went for the creating a template route, work pretty well! Thank you! However, I've created a workflow with sharepoint designer for the list and the workflow just wont apply to the template. I guess I can give that new app that I've created via the template the same workflow afterwards, but is there a way to make it automatically come with the template?

Comment: @DanielM as far is I know you can't save the template with the workflow included. What you could do is write code to create the list from the template and add the workflow afterwards.
An easier way would be adding the Workflow to the Task contenttype so the tasklist will have it by default. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514190(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: As I've understood it I have to redo the whole task list but with a content type as some sort of base, (still not too familiar with content types after research) and then add the workflow to the content type. How would that work practically for the people who's gonna use it? Would it be like a template that they can use and the workflow would be included?

Comment: @DanielM You need to modify the .stp and add the associated contenttype id manually (lists create their own version of a contenttype and you need the original to make this work). Afterwards it should work as described.

Comment: Would you like to guide a newbe a little? So the template I've created does not have the same content type ID as the original list's content type's ID? The list that the workflow works on. So the trick is to manually edit the .stp and make them have the same ID? Figured out how to open the .xml from the .stp and I can find some ContentTypeID="0x" here and there. And I know how to see the ID of a content type. Do I replace the 0x with that ID?

Comment: @DanielM I modified my answer

Comment: Woow thank you for your time that was very informative! Getting the hang of content types now.